# Are imaginary eigenvalues a fatal flaw when doing a factor analysis?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, parallel-analysis

I am running an exploratory factor analysis (EFA) in R, extracting three factors (determined via parallel analysis).

```
efa3 <- fa(d.wide.nn, nfactors =3, rotate = "oblimin", fm = 'pa', max.iter = 100000)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: NaNs producedWarning: imaginary eigen value condition encountered in fa
 Try again with SMC=FALSE 
 exiting faError in if (s < eps) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Warning: The requested transformaton failed, Promax was used instead as an oblique transformationError in La.svd(B) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

If I re-run the analysis with `SMC = False` it does run. However, I'm not sure if the fact that I got the error to begin with should give me pause before continuing. In addition, the fit statistics for the model with `SMC = FALSE` are strange:

```
Test of the hypothesis that 3 factors are sufficient.
The degrees of freedom for the model is 0  and the objective function was  0 
The number of observations was  3926  with Chi Square =  14.07  with prob <  NA 

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSA) is  0.01 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  NA 

Tucker Lewis Index of factoring reliability =  -Inf
```

This all makes me wonder if I should resort to a simpler factor structure.

Some more details: I have 3926 observations, and six variables.

Comment: It is mathematically impossible for the eigenvalue of a symmetric real matrix to be imaginary.  This error therefore indicates that floating point imprecision has perturbed the eigenvalues.  Because such a perturbation would be tiny (on the order of $10^{-16}$), such errors indicate you are working with a singular matrix.

Comment: 3 factors out of 6 variables is definitely too much. Even 2 factors may turn much. Practically, it is unusual to do a factor analysis on less then about 10 variables. Maybe for theoretical pursuits only..

Answer (score 1):

##### Omitted Part of Original Answer

*I originally deleted this part of the answer based on commentary below. However, I believe that it decontextualizes the comments so I have added it back in so it makes sense.*

The biggest issue you have here is that you likely have too few variables to meaningfully produce three factors. I think at a minimum you should have at least three or four items per factor, but it is much safer to simply create many items and see if they produce a reasonable factor solution. Doing anything with six items is difficult enough if there are problems with your items, but made even more complex if you are trying to spread that out between three factors, particularly if they poorly load onto a latent factor already. That is probably the most important nugget. While you can theoretically obtain a factor with just two items, they need to load onto the latent variable pretty well (aka be strongly correlated with each other) for that to happen.

Since you can't retest these people, you are probably stuck with either a two- or one-factor solution. Whether that is achievable is another story, but I think in your situation there is no other option. That likely isn't a major problem if you can get it to work, but you may need to adapt your theoretical explanation of why this may be the case. Anyway, that may ultimately be a good thing, because it can be difficult to meaningfully interpret a two-item factor anyway if the items don't provide a solid explanation of what people are being tested on.

##### Core Answer

There is certainly something wrong with your factor analysis and given the fit statistics look wonky (and as whuber notes the implausibility due to singularity), I would abandon ship with the factor solution you got. There are a series of steps you can employ to check what's going on. I tried to put them in some kind of order, but some of these you may need to go back to after accomplishing other steps.

1. **A large culprit can be a lack of variation in items.** Check your items for linear constants (those which literally only have one response) or near linear constants (items which have extremely low variation). This can be simply achieved by tabulating counts or running bar plots of the items. If you have a binary item with bar plots that just include $1$ as the recorded response, this item is basically useless. From my experience, this has been a common but substantial problem in factor analyses I have run in the past. Thankfully, it is also the most easily fixable problem if you have an adequate number of items.
2. **Check the determinant or the eigenvalues of your matrix**. This is easily accomplished in R. If you have a correlation matrix named `mat`, you can simply run `det(mat)` or `eigen(mat)` to obtain the determinant and the eigenvalues (though see the comments below for limitations to the former, in which the eigenvalues may provide a more useful check). If the determinant is extremely close to zero, this can cause some major instability in estimation and if it is *exactly* zero this means the matrix is singular. This often can crop up when you have perfect or near perfect collinearity between items, but **the opposite** can also happen if you have very poor correlations between items, particularly if there are *a lot* of them.
3. **Inspect your item correlation matrix.** I find this to be bewilderingly uncommon when people estimate factor analyses, and yet it is often one of the clearest steps to checking if your items are behaving like you expect them to. If for example you get two distinct color patterns in a correlation heatmap (one group of items clusters together a lot in correlation strength while another is barely correlated), this will often clue you in on how many factors are sensible. This will also be important if the above determinant check fails, as you can identify which items are the main culprits.
4. **The number of items is important.** If you have a ton of items on a test, this can sometimes complicate matters (note: this is a much better problem than having *too few* items, where you sometimes end up with catastrophic dumpster fires that simply can't be put out). If you have many zero or near-zero elements in your matrix (which contributes to the issue I highlighted above), this can cause it to become very unstable with many items. There are multiple options here. If you have a lot of items, you can simply remove some which are especially problematic. If you need to retain as many items as possible or removing items doesn't fix the issue, another method is to employ a PCA smoothing of the correlation matrix. This can be accomplished with the `cor.smooth` function in the `psych` package and works remarkably well.
5. **Factor solution is simply poor.** If you notice after checking your correlations there are patterns as I noted, I would definitely suggest changing your factor solution to include more/less based on what you see. If its not totally clear from the others checks what makes sense, one can also run a parallel analysis and compare it to the original raw data analysis (it appears from your syntax you already have, so I would plot that and see what that looks like).

Comment: 3926 observations for 6 variables is plenty for doing a factor analysis, so I don't find your explanation credible.  Instead consider the possibility that the matrix is singular.

Comment: Well this is part of why I mention that checking the determinant or the eigenvalues would be helpful (to check for NPD matrices). My major point isn't about 6 variables...its about 6 variables split between three factors, which is a very different thing. But I will edit out the first part of my answer and defer to your wisdom, as I think the rest of my answer approaches the core issue of figuring out how to improve the EFA fitting anyway.

Comment: I'm just commenting to point out that checking whether a determinant is close to zero is a bad way to evaluate matrix full-rankedness. Instead, one should examine the smallest singular/eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: Never heard of that before. Is there a reason why using the determinant in this case is bad? I assume you mean when it is near zero and not *actually* zero.

Comment: Determinants are expensive to compute, uncertain, and can underflow and overflow standard floating representations.  That's usually not a problem with a $6\times 6$ matrix but it quickly becomes one as the dimensions grow.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539436 for some analysis and related suggestions.

Comment: Thanks that is useful to know. I'll edit that part of my answer.